# How to uninstall and reinstall a module?

Tags: module, installation

Anyone know how I can uninstall and then reinstall the module? I believe it has some code that runs on install which I have edited so need to be able to run this again?

Thanks

Comment: when u install module with `setup:upgrade` one entry Entry in `setup_module` is place with your **module name** and **version**.. u can delete that entry and reinstall module.

Comment: Just to confirm that setup:upgrade will reinstall the module and will pick up my changes made?

Comment: what type of changes u  ask for.?

Comment: for more info u can refer [THIS](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall.html#instgde-install-magento-update)